# asp.net mvc LabelFor. Error at use array in the name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, model, label, naming

```
public class ScheduleModel
{

[DisplayName("Example")]
public bool DayOff { get; set; }

}

public class SimpleModel
{

public List<ScheduleModel> ScheduleContainer { get; set; }   

}


html

<%= Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ScheduleContainer[a].DayOff)%>
<%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.ScheduleContainer[a].DayOff)%>
```

It's code generate

```
<input id="ScheduleContainer_2__DayOff" name="ScheduleContainer[2].DayOff" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="ScheduleContainer[2].DayOff" type="hidden" value="false" />
<label for="ScheduleContainer[2]_DayOff">Example</label>
```

Why lablefor == **ScheduleContainer[2]_DayOff** though should be **ScheduleContainer_2__DayOff**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in MVC 2. It has been fixed in MVC 3.